# Ignore formula blanks in range

Tags: excel, vba

I need a way to set my range to be all cells with values, however in my "blank" cells I actually have formulas that make the cell blank.

I read another forum that used

```
[match(2,1/(F6:F55<>""))]
```

As a solution to ignore Formula Blanks but I don't see how to incorporate that into my code as it's looking for a range.

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
     Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Worksheets("analysis 1").[match(2,1/(F6:F55<>""))], _
        Worksheets("analysis 1").[match(2,1/(F6:F55<>""))], False, False, 90, Worksheets("Regression").Range("$A$1") _
        , False, False, False, False, , False
    Range("K1").Select
End Sub
```

Using

```
Range(Range("F6"), Range("F55").End(xlDown)).Select
```

will give me an error due to it having blanks in the range.

Comment: Try changing the `xlDown` to `xlUp`

Comment: Same issue assuming I start at F55

Answer (score 0):

This is some workaround to make a range only of the cells, that are corresponding to a certain condition:

```
Option Explicit

Function makeRangeWithoutBlanks(rngInput As Range) As Range

    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In rngInput

        If Len(rngCell) Then
            If makeRangeWithoutBlanks Is Nothing Then
                Set makeRangeWithoutBlanks = rngCell
            Else
                Set makeRangeWithoutBlanks = Union(rngCell, makeRangeWithoutBlanks)
            End If
        End If

    Next rngCell

    If makeRangeWithoutBlanks Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 999, Description:="No value!"

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim k As Range
    Set k = makeRangeWithoutBlanks(Range("A1:A100"))
    Debug.Print k.Address

End Sub
```

Run the `TestMe` to see the cells with value in `A1:A100`.

Comment: I was not able to achieve anything using this. There must be a simpler way?

Comment: What was your input? It should work, it returns a range with values or an error, if there are no values in the range

Answer (score 0):

What I have concluded is to use an Offset compiled with a CountIf value.
The CountIf will output the number of values in my range. Using that along with the OffSet will effectively select the range with values.

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    Dim n As Range
' D67 is a CountIf in order to find the number I plan to OffSet
    Set n = Worksheets("Data Input & Summary").Range("D67")
     Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Worksheets("analysis 1").Range(Range("F6"), Range("F6").End(xlDown).Offset(-n)), _
        Worksheets("analysis 1").Range(Range("G6"), Range("G6").End(xlDown).Offset(-n)), False, False, 90, Worksheets("Regression").Range("$A$1") _
        , False, False, False, False, , False
    Range("K1").Select
End Sub
```